# How can I run a loop process on a Heroku instance (Rails 4)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a Heroku Rails 4 app where I want something to run continuously. It is processing data from Amazon SQS.

Right now, I use clock.rb to continuously add a delayed job to run a worker. The worker is set to run for 10m, then finishes. Since the clock.rb is running every 30 seconds, it should restart a new process pretty quickly.

My Procfile is:

```
myworker: QUEUE=myworker bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to change the Procfile perhaps, so that I could say "Every instance of myworker should run this process while it is alive. If it dies for whatever reason, restart it immediately and start processing again"

Is there a good way to do that with Rails 4 and Heroku?

There must be... I don't really know what this is called but surely there's a name for this.

Also, once I have it running, would there be a good way to say "close the process every 10m, and restart, just to clear your memory/restart fresh"?

Comment: have you looked at EventMachine or Sidekiq? Not exactly sure what you're trying to do but they might be helpful.

Comment: I think there should be a way to run it w/o any delayed jobs. I just want it to be "start this instance and give it 100% towards running this process, w/o any need for a queue or delayed job"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do it with Delayed Job or anything like that; you just have to create a custom Rake task.

For instance, at my work we have this line in our Procfile:

`jobs_worker: bundle exec rake poll_jobs`

We added a `file_jobs.rake` file in `lib/tasks`, which does this:

`task poll_jobs: :environment do
  while true
    puts "polling jobs"
    FileJob.poll_status!
    sleep 10
  end
end`

We put in the extra sleep 10 so that a replacement task doesn't spin up right away. But you can take that out. The moment your task completes, it will automatically be restarted again. Keep in mind that if you keep restarting too often, Heroku might get mad at you and not spin your task right up again.

You could just as easily put a timer in there, or a 'number of times you make it around the loop' - and exit when the timer expires, or the number of times you've been through the loop is greater than 'x'.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to try that.

Comment: Cool - I just noticed there's a ```while true ``` component in there; we have that so our process runs 'forever' - you can have yours exit occasionally (but not too frequently as I warned, Heroku will probably get mad if you keep restarting your process too often).

Also know that if your process crashes or goes over-memory, Heroku will kill it for you, and then they will spin it right back up.